# Building Monthly aggregate from Daily table

Tags: sql, aggregate, teradata, vertica

I have written the code below to check for unique customers for the last 30 days. How would I repurpose this code to check for unique customers on a month start date. I am trying to build a monthly aggregate using table_billing that has a daily grain. Can you please guide me.

```
select 'context.processingDate' as rptg_dt, COALESCE(item_type,'ALL_ITEMS') as item_type, unique_customers
from (select 
        (case when item_type_code in ('A') then 'Books'
         when item_type_code in ('B','C') then 'Toys'
         else 'Fruits' end
         ) as item_type,
        count(distinct person_id) as unique_customers
      from table_billing
      where rptg_dt between cast('context.processingDate' as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')-30 
        AND cast('context.processingDate' as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        and item_type_code in ('A','B','C','D','E')
      group by CUBE(1)
    ) a;
```

Desired Output:

```
Monthly Start Date    | Item Type     | Unique Customers

5/1/14                | Books            | 100

5/1/14                | Toys             | 80

5/1/14                | Fruits           | 25

5/1/14                | ALL_ITEMS        | 175

6/1/14                | Books            | 80

6/1/14                | Toys             | 60

6/1/14                | Fruits           | 40

6/1/14                | ALL_ITEMS        | 95
```

I am looking to re-write this query as follows:

```
select 'context.processingDate' as month_start_dt, 
COALESCE(item_type,'ALL_ITEMS') as item_type, unique_customers
from (select 
(case when item_type_code in ('A') then 'Books'
when item_type_code in ('B','C') then 'Toys'
else 'Fruits' end
) as item_type,
count(distinct person_id) as unique_customers
from table_billing
where month_start_dt = cast('context.processingDate' as date format'YYYY-MM-DD') and item_type_code in ('A','B','C','D','E') group by CUBE(1)) a;
```

How would I tweak the query to make this possible? Thank you!

Comment: What is the best way to format the code in a stackoverflow post, please? Thanks!

Comment: add sample data and desired result

Comment: So rather than doing BETWEEN the last 30 days you just want to check the first day of the month? Or, do you want to know between the processing date and the first day of the month?

Comment: @Error_2646 I just want to check the first day of the month. I included the desired output as well just now. The context processing date is for the ETL process to check every day for the next row that is the first day of the month.

Comment: @sqlstacking If the rest of the query is working how you want, cant you just change       where rptg_dt between cast('context.processingDate' as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')-30 
        AND cast('context.processingDate' as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD') with cast('context.processingDate' as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD') - EXTRACT(DAY FROM cast('context.processingDate' as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')) + 1? Or just add a filter for the day part to be 1?

Comment: @Error_2646 I added a clarification to my question. Does that help clarify what I am seeking please? Thank you for the attention!

Comment: How does your queries work? Where is *content_type* in the derived table? Maybe `CUBE(1)`?

Comment: @Parfait that should read as item_type. I just changed it in the code in the question. Thanks for pointing it out.